# AUC metrics on XGBoost

Tags: r, xgboost, auc

I build my model for prediction with XGBoost:

```
setDT(train)
setDT(test)

labels <- train$Goal
ts_label <- test$Goal
new_tr <- model.matrix(~.+0,data = train[,-c("Goal"),with=F]) 
new_ts <- model.matrix(~.+0,data = test[,-c("Goal"),with=F])

labels <- as.numeric(labels)-1
ts_label <- as.numeric(ts_label)-1

dtrain <- xgb.DMatrix(data = new_tr,label = labels) 
dtest <- xgb.DMatrix(data = new_ts,label=ts_label)

params <- list(booster = "gbtree", objective = "binary:logistic", eta=0.3, gamma=0, max_depth=6, min_child_weight=1, subsample=1, colsample_bytree=1)

xgb1 <- xgb.train(params = params, data = dtrain, nrounds = 291, watchlist = list(val=dtest,train=dtrain), print_every_n = 10, 
                   early_stop_round = 10, maximize = F , eval_metric = "error")


xgbpred <- predict(xgb1,dtest)
xgbpred <- ifelse(xgbpred > 0.5,1,0)

confusionMatrix(xgbpred, ts_label)

Confusion Matrix and Statistics

          Reference
Prediction    0    1
         0 1904   70
         1  191 2015

               Accuracy : 0.9376               
                 95% CI : (0.9298, 0.9447)     
    No Information Rate : 0.5012               
    P-Value [Acc > NIR] : < 0.00000000000000022

                  Kappa : 0.8751               
 Mcnemar's Test P-Value : 0.0000000000001104   

            Sensitivity : 0.9088               
            Specificity : 0.9664               
         Pos Pred Value : 0.9645               
         Neg Pred Value : 0.9134               
             Prevalence : 0.5012               
         Detection Rate : 0.4555               
   Detection Prevalence : 0.4722               
      Balanced Accuracy : 0.9376               

       'Positive' Class : 0
```

This accuracy suits me, but I want to check the metric of auc. I write:

```
xgb1 <- xgb.train(params = params, data = dtrain, nrounds = 291, watchlist = list(val=dtest,train=dtrain), print_every_n = 10, 
                   early_stop_round = 10, maximize = F , eval_metric = "auc")
```

But after that i don't know how to make a prediction concerning AUC metrics. I need your help, because its my first experience with XGBoost. Thanks.

UPD: As far as I understand, after the auc metric I need a coefficient that I will cut classes. Now I cut off in 0,5

Comment: what do you mean make prediction concerning AUC? AUC Is just a performance metric of a classifier. If you optimize w.r.t AUC not accuracy, you will have a different function but its ouput will be the same anyway. Try to use xgb1 to predict as well..

Comment: @JanSila i got [291] val-auc:0.978914 train-auc:1.000000  when fitting with auc metrics. But if i make prediction like a xgb1, values doesnt changes. Same as error metrics.

Answer (score 6):

You can see your AUC value of the trained model for the training data set with following

```
> max(xgb1$evaluation_log$train_auc)
```

Also you can calculate it for your predictions on test set with pROC package as follows

```
> library(pROC) 
> roc_test <- roc( test_label_vec, predictions_for_test, algorithm = 2)
```

for your code written with your parameters it is

```
> roc_test <- roc(ts_label, xgbpred, algorithm = 2)
> plot(roc_test ) 
> auc(roc_test )
```

if you want to calculate AUC and plot ROC curve for your training set, you can use following

```
> roc_training <- roc(train_output_vec, train_predictions, algorithm = 2)
> plot(roc_training )   
> auc(roc_training)
```

ROC curve and AUC does not need to consider the cutoff point. ROC is being drawn and AUC is calculated sorting the prediction scores and seeing what % of target events are found in the prediction set. So, it is checking what % of target events you could find if you move the cutoff point. The decision of the cutoff point is related to costs, or application of the algorithm. You can make a search on cutoff to get more info on this.

Answer (score 0):

**I edit the code:**

You can do it directly with the confussion matrix:

```
cm<-confusionMatrix(xgbpred, ts_label)$table
t = cm[1,1]/(cm[1,1]+cm[2,1])
f = cm[2,2]/(cm[2,1]+cm[2,2])

AUC = (1+t-f)/2
```

Comment: sry, it doesnt work, Error in cm [1, 1]: wrong number of measurements

Comment: Can you please do ls(cm) and class(cm) and show me the result??

Comment: > ls(cm)
[1] "byClass"  "dots"     "mode"     "overall"  "positive" "table"

> class(cm)
[1] "confusionMatrix"

Comment: What interpretation of this AUC? Is this a coef that  i can cut off my responses?

Answer (score 0):

There are different methods for finding a good cutoff threshold and different reasons why you might want to do this- for example, an imbalance of class labels in your dataset or because you want to tune the specificity or sensitivity.

One example of this would be in a classifier for predicting whether a patient has the early onset of a disease, where the cost of a false-positive might be quite high, so it’s better to keep the specificity high even if that means also possibility sacrificing the sensitivity and potentially having some false negatives.

There are different methods for constructing this cutoff from a ROC curve or from a precision/recall curve. In the case I just mentioned above, which is often used with genetic bio markers, you could use the Youdin Index (a vertical line drawn from the “line of equal chance“ to the ROC curve) to construct this point.